# Error Using SharedPreferences() Method In Android Studio (Login Activity) After Adding Firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, sharedpreferences

My code worked until I added Firebase to it.
This is my login page, and the SharedPreferences don't work.
When I click on the login button, the password pops up as the username and the password - and then when I re-run the emulator - the username and the password are null.
Please help me find the error:

````
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText username;
    EditText etPassword;
    Button loginBtn;
    Button registerBtn;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private static String TAG = "Michael's Tracking --> ";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Log.d(TAG, "Start onCreate");

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.toLoginBtn);

        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            super.onStart();
            // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(currentUser != null){
                currentUser.reload();
            }

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = etPassword.getText().toString();

                String stName = email;
                mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.name), stName);
                mEditor.commit();

                String stPassword = pass;
                mEditor.putString(getString(R.string.password), stPassword);
                mEditor.commit();

                checkSharedPreferences();

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class));
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent registerPage = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(registerPage);

            }
        });
    }

    private void checkSharedPreferences() {
        String stName, stPassword;
        stName = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.name), "");
        stPassword = mPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.password), "");
        username.setText(stName);
        etPassword.setText(stPassword);
    }

}```

Thank you very much!
````

Comment: Your method `checkSharedPreferences` is only called on `loginBtn` clicked. You need to call is outside to check if data is in shared Preferences on relaunch of app

Answer (score 0):

`checkSharedPreferences()` method shouldn't be called inside `onClick`, it's for restoring data, so it should be called at the beginning, so in `onCreate` after taking references to `View`s (`findViewById`) and preferences (`mPreferences`, `mEditor`)

Comment: Thank you! When I moved the SharedPreferences() method out of the onClick, it kind of worked; the password appears as the email/username, too!

Comment: @MichaelS can you add your updated code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference to store username and password after successful login.

```
      mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new
                                OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                            mEditor.putString("Useranme", stName);

                                            mEditor.putString("Password", stPassword);
                                                    mEditor.commit();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class));
                                        } else {
                                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! When I moved the SharedPreferences() method out of the onClick - and after the authentication - it worked, but the password appeared as the username/email, as well :(